# Why doesn't Rails' asset_path() use config.assets.prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a fonts.css.scss.erb file with lines like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Kai';
    src: url(<%= asset_path 'BebasKai-Regular.otf' %>) format("opentype");
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Which my asset precompile step consolidates into the file public/assets/application-3a614235a1e8ce2c0106014a7063da43.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Kai';
  src: url(/dev-assets/BebasKai-Regular-df9ac02782e1ead197370c458418a29b.otf) format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

The only problem is that "`dev-assets`". I want to compile directly to `public/assets`, not `public/dev-assets`; so in development.rb, I'm doing

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
end
```

**Not** "`dev-assets`".

Changing this prefix does change the *directory* that my compiled assets go into. But it doesn't change the value that asset_path uses.

I see in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f2c04d77ba30695796b74aede49ba43fe50b133f/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L130) that asset_path is using `config.relative_url_root` and not `config.assets.prefix`. When I set this in development.rb like:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  config.assets.prefix = "/assets"
  config.relative_url_root = "/assets"
end
```

...it works:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Bebas Kai';
  src: url(/assets/BebasKai-Regular-88ddff7f039b7006c1fcfc9081783ecc.otf) format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

...but I'm hacking here and don't know the rhyme or reason behind what I'm doing.

**Why doesn't Rails' asset_path() use config.assets.prefix?**

Comment: Do you have "host" options set in your config. file?  The asset_path helper does take into account the relative url and through asset_url looks into the public folder accordingly.  Try commenting out assets.prefix since "/assets" is the default folder.  Precompile again, restart your server and maybe luck!

Comment: what are "host" options? can you point me to documentation on that?